# get index value from react loop and pass it to css

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I created react component that is taking an array and stacking all the progress bars into one.

```
const ProgressBar = (props, {...customProps}) => {

    const GroupProgressBar = [];
    props.groups.map((group, i) => {

      const widthValue = (group.value / group.max) * 100;

      GroupProgressBar.push

      (<div style={{width: `${widthValue}%`}}
      key = {i}

      className={`well-background--${group.concept}
                  animation
                  terra-ProgressGroup--progress
                  terra-ProgressBar--${props.heightSize}`}>

        </div>);
    })

    return <div className='terra-ProgressGroup'> {GroupProgressBar} </div>
}
```

CSS (classes below i want to convert to single class):

....

```
.well-background--concept1 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  z-index: -1;
}
.well-background--concept2 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  z-index: -2;
}
.well-background--concept3 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

I tried to convert these classes into one but have no luck

```
:root {
  --concept-code: key;
  --concept-code2: key;
}

.animation {
  animation-delay: var(--concept-code)s;
  z-index: var(--concept-code2);
}
```

Basically i dont want keep adding those similar classes so i am trying to create a single class and pass those numbers from react component. probably using `key = {i}`

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why even bother with CSS for this case? The point of CSS is that the styles *cascade* and have hierarchy. If the style applies only to a specific React component, then it's best to render the appropriate styles directly.

```
const ProgressBar = (props, {...customProps}) => {

    const GroupProgressBar = [];
    props.groups.map((group, i) => {

      const widthValue = (group.value / group.max) * 100;

      GroupProgressBar.push

      (<div 
      style={{
          width: `${widthValue}%`,
          animationDelay: /* based on the concept number */,
          zIndex: /* based on the concept number */
      }}
      key = {i}

      className={`well-background--${group.concept}
                  animation
                  terra-ProgressGroup--progress
                  terra-ProgressBar--${props.heightSize}`}>

        </div>);
    })

    return <div className='terra-ProgressGroup'> {GroupProgressBar} </div>
}
```

Note that I'm not sure how you can generate the appropriate number for your style because I don't know your data structure. But that would be trivial enough. The important part is just rendering the style in the component instead of CSS.

There's not really a great way to dynamically inject CSS class style definitions into the page with React. And even so, that would be vastly over-engineering a solution for this problem. Better to just create lots of `.well-background` class definitions in the CSS manually, as many as you think you'll need (10? 20? How many will there really be?).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to react. how could i extract the numeric value from string? string will be like concept1, concept2 etc.. I am accessing it inside className as group.concept. Groups is an array of concept and value.

Comment: tried something. how can i implement this in my component. ```const animationDelay = group.concept.match(/\d/g);
      animationDelay = animationDelay.join("");```

Comment: HI I tried to implement it. getting this ```Warning: a `div` tag (owner: `ProgressBar`) was passed a numeric string value for CSS property `animationDelay` (value: `1`) which will be treated as a unitless number in a future version of React.```

Comment: @User7354632781 `animation-delay` must be expressed in seconds or milliseconds, like `1s` or `300ms`. A simple value of `1` is unitless and can't be used properly.